# How could one rename a batch of column names in R and change only one digit, leaving the rest of the name the same?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rename, names

I have data from one survey with 30 items collected over two waves (i.e., time points). Items are labeled as follows: item1w1, item2w1, item3w1, etc., where w1 = wave 1. How can I rename all items by only changing the w1 to w2, leaving the rest of the item name the same as the original, without changing each item individually, as with dplyr::rename or some other method?

That is, item1**w1** = item1**w2**, item2**w1** = item2**w2**, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rename_with`:

```r
library(dplyr)
rename_with(your_dataframe, ~ gsub("w1", "w2", .x), ends_with("w1"))
#alternative:
#rename_with(your_dataframe, ~ gsub("w1$", "w2", .x))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `base R`

```
names(df) <- sub("w1$", "w2", names(df))
```